# Loaded class is from the wrong directory

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm having a really really weird bug.

I have two vhosts on one machine: staging and production.

They are located in /var/www/staging/ and /var/www/production/. I deploy my Symfony2 project via Capifony (a symfony2 extension of capistrano), so the web dir is in /var/www/staging/current/web/

When I `echo __DIR__` in my controller I get

```
/var/www/production/releases/20130424075147/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller
```

Which is correct. However, if I now get an entity from it's repository (for example)

```
$object = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Object')->findOneById(1);
```

And do `echo $object->getUploadRootDir()` (from [the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)), which uses `__DIR__` I suddenly get

```
/var/www/staging/releases/20130424075333/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Entity/../../../../web/upload/
```

Somehow, when loading the Object, it switched to the staging environment, instead of production (the two different release folders are just because there's different releases between production and staging).

Is this due to autoloading? A config error in the vhosts?

Below is are my two vhosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/production/current/web"
    ServerName  example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com example.com
    SetEnv      SYMFONY_ENV prod
    SetEnv      SYMFONY_DEBUG 0

    <Directory /var/www/production/current/web>
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/staging/current/web"
    ServerName  staging.example.com
    ServerAlias staging.example.com
    SetEnv      SYMFONY_ENV dev
    SetEnv      SYMFONY_DEBUG 1

    <Directory /var/www/staging/current/web>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What about some cache? Or Doctrine references...? Or Symfony/Doctrine configuration...? I guess You did just copy+pasted from staging into production or are You using any version controll tools (such as Git, SVN, ...)?

Comment: I am using Git and Capistrano to deploy. Our sysadmin helped me out, will post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was APC.

In app.php I had

```
$loader = new ApcClassLoader('sf', $loader);
```

which caused overlapping problems in the apc opcode entries (dixit our sysadmin).

The fix was simple:

```
    $loader = new ApcClassLoader($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $loader);
```